# How to get multiple Bottom Sheets, one on top of another working properly?

Tags: android

I have a two bottom sheets that you can drag from the bottom. You first drag one bottom sheet, then you can drag another on top of it. However if you dismiss one, another one gets dismissed too. I want to be able to dismiss the top sheet first then the bottom one, one by one. I have tried disabling the bottom one but both gets disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem. You need to create a custom bottom sheet behavior for this.

Layouts with two bottom sheet :

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_bottom_sheet_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.xxx.com.CustomBottomSheetBehavior"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="@{model.first_height}">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/> 

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_bottom_sheet_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.xxx.com.CustomBottomSheetBehavior"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="@{model.second_height}">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/> 

</FrameLayout>
```

I added the two fragments that I want to expand from the bottom into the fragment containers of the above layout.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.first_fragment_container, new FirstFragment())
                .commit();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.second_fragment_container, new SecondFragment())
                .commit();
```

Then I created a custom bottom sheet behavior.

```
public class CustomBottomSheetBehavior<V extends View> extends BottomSheetBehavior<V> 
{


private boolean enableCollapse = true;

public CustomBottomSheetBehavior() {
}

public CustomBottomSheetBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setEnableCollapse(boolean enableCollapse) {
    this.enableCollapse = enableCollapse;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, MotionEvent event) {
    if (enableCollapse==true) {
        return false;
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, event);

}
}
```

Now you add callbacks to the above bottom sheets.

```
FrameLayout firstBottomSheet = activity.findViewById(R.id.first_bottom_sheet_holder);
FrameLayout secondBottomSheet = activity.findViewById(R.id.second_bottom_sheet_holder);
CustomBottomSheetBehavior firstBottomSheetBehavior = (CustomBottomSheetBehavior)BottomSheetBehavior.from(firstBottomSheet);
CustomBottomSheetBehavior secondBottomSheetBehaviour = (CustomBottomSheetBehavior)BottomSheetBehavior.from(secondBottomSheet);


firstBottomSheetBehaviour.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {



        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });





secondBottomSheetBehaviour.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {


            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING||newState==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {

                firstBottomSheetBehavior .setEnableCollapse(false);

            }else if(newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                firstBottomSheetBehavior .setEnableCollapse(true);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });
```

All done.

Comment: where did you get bottomSheetBehavior behavior from ? what is this variable ? for example, you call bottomSheetBehavior.setEnableCollapse(false); where is bottomSheetBehavior defined ?

Comment: @j2emanue That bottomSheetBehavior variable should be firstBottomSheetBehavior. Didn't notice this when I answered. See the edits, I have fixed it now.